# How can I clear references to Javascript functions that no longer exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project that uses AJAX to download HTML, CSS and Javascript in one singe chunk of text then appends it to an element on the page. Here is the code:

```
_t.stage.empty();
_t.stage.html(DATA);
```

This works fine.

Here is the problem:

After adding the HTML to the stage, I call this function:

```
if(initApp != null && typeof(initApp) == "function") initApp();// Checks for initApp(). If exists, executes.
```

If I load a page that has this function, then load one that does NOT have this function, the function from the first page is executed. Here is some psuedo code to understand the results.

page 1:

```
This is a page.
 <style>...</style>
 <script> function initApp(){ alert("hello"); } </script>
```

When this page is run, an alert box with the text 'hello' is shown.

page 2: (no initApp() function)

```
  This is page 2.
  <style>...</style>
```

When the page is run, an alert box with the text 'hello' is shown.

Please note: These pages are loaded with AJAX and inserted into the HTML of an already loaded page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy to tell exactly what you're trying to do, but if what you're trying to do is make it so that some other code that calls `initApp()` will cause nothing to happen when it calls that, then you can simply redefine the function to a do-nothing function like this:

```
initApp = function() {}
```

The most recent definition of a function takes precedence (e.g. replaces any prior definitions).

If your newly loaded code contains an implementation of `initApp()` that you don't want called the second time the script is loaded, then you're out of luck.  You can't stop that.  You will need to change the structure of your code so that the dynamically loaded code doesn't execute stuff you don't want to be executed.  There are many different ways you could do that.  For example, you could have a global boolean that keeps track of whether the init code has been called yet.

```
var initCalled = false;

function initApp() {
    if (!initCalled) {
        initCalled = true;
        // rest of initialization code here
    }
}

initApp();   // will only actually do anything the first time it's called
             // even if it is loaded more than once
```

---

It appears from the comments that you seem to think that reloading a script tag with different code will somehow make code from the previous script go away.  It will not.  Once a function is loaded, it stays loaded unless it is redefined to mean something else or unless some code explicitly removed a property from an object.  It does not matter how the code was loaded or whether it was in the core page or an external script file.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to do `initApp = undefined` or `initApp = null`

Comment: @royhowie - If some code is calling `initApp()`, those will cause `initApp()` to throw an exception which I don't think is what the OP wants.

Comment: `if(initApp != null && typeof(initApp) == "function") initApp();` It doesn't make sense to initialize in more than one place. Either way, doesn't matter.

Comment: I have an HTML page that is already loaded. I download these pages that have the HTML, CSS and Javascript all in one text. That text is added to an element on the HTML page. Then this function is called. So, it appears, when functions are loaded, they stay in memory even though they are not loaded as a script file.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss - one a page is loaded, functions defined in that page don't go away.  It does not matter how they were defined (in the core page or in an external script file). I'm not sure what you're previous comment means.  See the newly added paragraph at the end of my answer.

Comment: If you have ever worked with something like jQuery Mobile you might be familiar with the idea. One main HTML page exists. It has an area that is changed out with 'pages' provided through AJAX. SO the entire page is not reloaded, just a specific region of it. It is for a game I am working on. SO, it is not exactly 'standard' javascript programming. Anyway, your answer solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss - other options added to my answer.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss - You're asking the wrong question, you don't won't to remove functions, you want to simply not load them more than once, and the way to do that with a single page app/site is just loading the scripts once and changing just markup.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying. But the thing is, in this application, each 'page' is meant to be an individual 'application' that uses Javascript . The freshly loaded 'page' needs to be initialized somehow once it is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

> Javascript functions that no longer exist

This is a bad premise. The functions still exist, which is obvious from the fact that the second AJAX load ended up executing it. The fact that the `<script>` tags are replaced and no longer in the document doesn't undefine the function. It's like asking why is your TV still broken if the burglar that broke it is no longer there.

There are two basic things you can do:

a) Clear the function explicitly yourself:

```
if (initApp != null && typeof(initApp) == "function") {
    initApp();
    delete window.initApp;
}
```

b) Change the function name to be unique per AJAX page (or namespace the function with the same idea), probably tied to the name of the AJAX page, so you can invoke it in a more specific manner.